# How can I interpret natural logarithm transformed value in the binary regression result

Tags: r, regression, logistic, interpretation, logarithm

I have the binominal regression output result using R programming and **x3** below is the natural logarithm of the data which is large. The **x3** before imposing the natural logarithm has the following descriptive statistics:

```
    Min     1065530
    Max     7250000000
    Mean    842062274.8
    Median  500000000
```

I am trying to provide an economic interpretation of increasing one unit of **x3**. However, as **x3** itself is in natural logarithm and has coefficient of -1.598 as below, I am not sure how to interpret this coefficient in this case. The binary regression output is as below:

```
    > x_reg=glm(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6+x7+x8+x9+x10+x11+x12+x13+x14, data=DATA, family=binomial(link="logit"))                 
    > summary(x_reg)                    

    Call:                   
    glm(formula = y ~x1 + x2 +x3 +                  
        x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + x8 +                    
       x9 + x10 + x11 + x12 + x13                   
       + x14, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = DATA)                   

    Deviance Residuals:                     
        Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max                     
    -2.6596  -0.6843  -0.3166   0.7505   2.4914                     

    Coefficients:                   
                    Estimate    Std. Error  z value Pr(>|z|)    
    (Intercept)     27.372022   9.5791     2.857    0.004271    **
    x1              0.572836    0.236129    2.426   0.015269    *
    x2              0.437914    1.40225     0.312   0.754817    
    x3             -1.597899    0.491549    -3.251  0.001151    **
    x4             -0.591385    0.333672    -1.772  0.076336    .
    x5              0.881187    0.264665    3.329   0.00087     ***
    x6              0.126759    0.060748    2.087   0.036923    *
    x7             -0.270982    0.429146    -0.631  0.52775 
    x8              0.020369    0.372997    0.055   0.956449    
    x9             -3.580657    0.932135    -3.841  0.000122    ***
    x10             0.22745     0.092035    2.471   0.01346     *
    x11            -0.01306     0.020641    -0.633  0.526921    
    x12             0.009792    0.023543    0.416   0.677482    
    x13             0.002869    0.01344     0.213   0.830976    
    x14            -0.010232    0.055211    -0.185  0.852973    
    ---                 
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1                  

    (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)                    

        Null deviance: 181.05  on 131  degrees of freedom                   
    Residual deviance: 124.43  on 117  degrees of freedom                   
      (390 observations deleted due to missingness)                 
    AIC: 154.43                 

    Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

May I know how to interpret the **x3** which is in natural logarithm?

Comment: Is there any utility in expressing X3 in millions, such that the min becomes 1.06553 and the max becomes 7250? That way no log transform would be needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can linearize the natural logarithm (which has derivative $1 / x$) to get to this:

> For every one-unit change in the original $x_3$ near specific point $x_3^*$, there's a change of $+ \beta_3 / x_3^*$ in the log odds or $\times e^{\beta_3 / x_3^*} $ in the odds.

If you really want one number for the effect of $x_3$, then you could plug in the mean for $x_3^*$ but note that's an approximation that gets worse as you move away from the mean.

More direct interpretations of $\beta_3$ are:

1. The amount the log odds of the event decreases for every $e$-fold (approximately 2.7 times) increase in the raw value of $x_3$. The multiplier $e$ is the base of the logarithm you used.
2. The power $k$ of the [power-law relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law) between the odds of the event and $x_3$, while all other covariates are held constant.

The second interpretation comes from:
$$
\text{log(odds)} = \textit{stuff} + \beta_3 \log(x_3)
$$
$$
\text{odds} = e^{\textit{stuff}} e^{\log(x_3^{\beta_3})}
$$
$$
\text{odds} = e^{\textit{stuff}} x_3^{\beta_3}
$$
though I don't know it would be especially useful in this case given $x_3^{\beta_3}$ is going to be very close to zero for the values in your data set (with a very large intercept to counteract it).

Comment: Let’s say x3 is the firm size measured by total asset of a firm with the descriptive statistics as shown above. If so, how would it be economically interpreted in this case in unit increase wise?

Comment: Could you explain where the "2.7" comes from?  There may be some ambiguity concerning whether you are discussing $x_3$ or the original data $\exp(x_3).$

Comment: @whuber, thx for the feedback - attempted to resolve the ambiguities. Eric, I took another shot at it to provide a more direct answer to your question. It's based on a pretty crude approximation so take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: Well I'm afraid we won't have economically practical answer based on the nature of the problem. However, if there are any, it would be awesome.